# babel-loader is not interpolating in transpiled file

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-loader

I'm learning webpack, and have a simple javascript that uses a bit of ES6.

```
function sayHello(){
  let tool = 'webpack';
  alert('Hello I am ${tool}, welcome to ES6');
}

/*module.exports = sayHello;*/

// use ES6 modules
export { sayHello };
```

I've configured a babel-loader like so

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I check the transpiled file I see that it converted the let to var, but I was expecting that it will interpolate the '${tool}' to something like '.concat(tool,...').

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@babel/preset-env` will only use transformations for specific targets. That means only a couple of transformations are applied if the environment targeted is fairly new or a lot of transformations are applied if the targeted environment is old.

You can check the default by using:

```
npx browserlist
```

Which should give you the list of browsers `@babel/preset-env` is targeting.

That being said though. What you have there does not require a transformation. You are probably thinking on template literals:

```
alert(`Hello I am ${tool}, welcome to ES6`);
```

*Notice the character `` ` `` is different from `'`*.

Which I believe should be transformed on default installations as of writing of this post. Since IE11 does not have support for template literals and it's on the browsers list.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know neither noticed that I need to change the quote charachter. This was my issue